# Ember-Simple-Auth currentUser example help required

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

So I realize that the account example here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/8863c032fcea6148a5b3365be5d66dc2389d301d/examples/4-authenticated-account.html

Provides the code for retrieving the currently logged in account. I just have a few questions about the example as I am trying to get it working in an Ember-CLI app.

`SimpleAuth` is being used in the example however, I don't know where it's coming from as I am trying to `import SimpleAuth from ...` but I don't know what file to import it from.

Furthermore, I am wondering if the response from the server now needs to return the user_id as well with the access_token/refresh_token?

If so, is that oauth compatible?

EDIT: My current code

```
// app/initializers/oauth-custom.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import OAuthCustomAuthenticator from 'front/authenticators/oauth-custom';
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';


export default {
    name: 'oauth-custom',
    before: 'simple-auth',

    initialize: function(container) {
        Session.reopen({
            currentUser: function() {
                var user_id = this.get('user_id');
                if (!Ember.isEmpty(user_id)) {
                    return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', user_id);
                }
            }.property('user_id')
        });
        container.register(
            'oauth-custom:oauth2-password-grant',
            OAuthCustomAuthenticator
        );
    }
};
```

Authentication works out perfectly, it's just that I don't see any call /user/id that ember tries to make.

Sample response from the server:

```
{
    "access_token": "asdf",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires": 1406082157,
    "expires_in": 604800,
    "refresh_token": "asdf",
    "user_id": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SimpleAuth global is only defined in the browserified distribution of the library. When you're using ember-cli you import the individual components instead of accessing them via the global (see e.g. this example: http://log.simplabs.com/post/90339547725/using-ember-simple-auth-with-ember-cli).

To e.g. get the session you'd do sty like:

```
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

Session.reopen({
  …
});
```

The example linked above requires the server to include the `user_id` in the response which is not compliant with the OAuth 2.0 specification but a customization. If you want/need to be compliant you could get the current user e.g. via a `GET /me` or sth. like that once the session is authenticated.

Comment: I've updated my question with sample code and response from the server.

Comment: So the problem is not solved? Can you provide the source code of your authenticator?

Comment: It seems to work actually after I made a change. Thanks for the help :)